# Explicit instantiation failing with gcc - why?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I have the following (simplified, and thus silly) code:

```
template <typename Function, Function f, typename... Arguments>
void call_wrapper(Arguments... arguments)
{
    f(arguments...);
}
```

and then:

```
void foo() { return; }
template void call_wrapper<decltype(foo), foo>();

void bar(int x) { return; }
template void call_wrapper<decltype(bar), bar, int>(int x);
```

When I compile this with clang 3.5.0, it works; but if I try to compile it with gcc 4.9.3 or 5.1.1, I get:

```
a.cpp:10:15: error: template-id ‘call_wrapper<void(), foo>’ for ‘void call_wrapper()’ does not match any template declaration
 template void call_wrapper<decltype(foo), foo>();
               ^
a.cpp:13:15: error: template-id ‘call_wrapper<void(int), bar, int>’ for ‘void call_wrapper(int)’ does not match any template declaration
 template void call_wrapper<decltype(bar), bar, int>(int x);
               ^
```

Why is that?

**Note:** I'm more interested in a C++11 answer than a C++14/C++17 answer, if there's any difference. That's how I'm invoking gcc, anyway.

Comment: That compiles with clang but fails with gcc [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f53a7b80bf19e831).

Comment: @Jarod42: Damn. Edited question with some info regarding my own compiler and standards version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `decltype(fun)` where `fun` is a function is, well, the type of the function. Although using `fun` looks remarkably like it should have the same type, it is actually not: you cannot have an object of a function type, i.e., the type of fun, when passed as an argument, happens to be `decltype(fun)*`. If you slip the pointer into the instantiation (as shown for `foo`) or explicitly decay the type before applying `decltype() (as shown for`bar`) it should work:

```
void foo() { return; }
template void call_wrapper<decltype(foo)*, foo>();

void bar(int x) { return; }
template void call_wrapper<decltype(+bar), bar, int>(int x);
```

I realize that there is a comment about the instantiation working with [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). It seems clang erronously accepts the original code.